# Joint probability of dependent continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, substitution

I was reading through wikipedia about joint probability.
I found out that for all random variables $$ f_{Y\mid X = x}(y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} $$
However, nowhere was I able to find how to algrebraically evaluate $ f_{Y\mid X = x}(y) $ or $ f_{X,Y}(x,y) $ except in terms of eachothers.

I tried deducing $ f_{X,Y}(x,y) $ myself where $ Y $ is a linear combination of the randoms $X$ and $Z$. This is where I got.

$$ Y = X + Z $$

$$ f_{Y\mid X = x}(y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} $$

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X = x \cap Y = y) $$
    $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X = x \cap X + Z = y) $$
    $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X = x \cap Z + x = y) $$
    $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X = x \cap Z = y - x) $$
    $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X,Z}(x,y - x) $$
    $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Z(y - x) $$
    $$ f_{Y\mid X = x}(y) = f_Z(y - x) $$

It seems to make sense to me, although I'm most uncertain about the substitution of $X$ for $x$. Is this allowed between the arguments of the union, or is there something that makes it different because $X = x$ and $Y = y$ are events rather than equations?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The notation really ought to be $f_{Y\,\mid\,X=x}(y)$ rather than $f_{Y\,\mid\,X}(y\mid x)$. $\qquad$

Comment: On the wiki I see (differing between pages) $p(y|x)$, $f_Y(y|X = x)$ get used with the same meaning, I assume that those are all the same as $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$. I don't know where I got $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ from though.

Comment: Unfortunately all of those are frequently seen. $\qquad$

Comment: But isn't $f_{Y \mid X=x}(y)$ dependent on $x$, shouldn't it therefore be in the parentheses?

Comment: It does depend on $x$, since it's a conditional distribution given the event $X=x$.  But as a density function it's a function of $y$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probability densities* are not *probability measures*, so you cannot equate them. $$~f_{Y,X}(y,x)\not=P(Y=y\cap X=x)~$$

However, the intuition is reasonably correct and you can manipulate them in an *analogous* manner; which is not always quite straightforward:

We use a change of variable transformation; based on the chain rule of calculus.

When $z=g(y,x)$ this is:

$$\begin{align}f_{Y,X}(y,x) = f_{Z,X}(g(y,x),x)~{\Big\lvert\dfrac{\partial g(y,x)}{\partial y}\Big\rvert} \end{align}$$

In this case $g(y,x)=y-x$ so it *is* simply:

$$f_{Y,X}(y,x) ~=~ f_{Z,X}(y-x,x)$$

---

*However* when, for example, $Y=2Z+X$ , then we use $g(y,x)=\tfrac {y-x}2$ so

$$f_{Y,X}(y,x) ~=~ \tfrac 12 f_{Z,X}(\tfrac {y-x}2,x)$$

[This should make sense when you realise that if continuous random variable $Y$ is spread twice as far as $Z$ (for any $X$), then its density will be halved.]

Comment: I understand where the equality with the chain rule comes from, but why is the absolute value used here? Is that just because a PDF can't be negative?

Comment: @S.Klumpers  Yes, that's exactly why we take the unsigned derivative.